# Identify which application is reading/writing on the hard drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, monitoring

Is there a similar tool to [Windows 7 Resource Monitor](http://www.pctipsbox.com/detect-what-process-is-thrashing-your-hard-drive/) in OS X that can show me how many I/O operations are being performed for each active process?

Comment: I am assuming you want something beyond the Activity Monitor? If so could you clarify this in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a wide Terminal window and enter the command:

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys
```

This will show all filesystem activity on the system, as it occurs.  It will show not only which processes are accessing the filesystem, but also what they are doing.